# This command is not available. By writing to Word with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

My powershell script yesterday stopped working. I have changed nothing in the code or in the path to files. It just stopped working. I can't explain it.

I've tested all path and all variables and its look fine.

```bsh
function Gen-Doc($Replace, $dataToRaplace, $user_name, $austauch) {
    $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
    $objWord.Visible = $false
    if ($austauch -eq $true) {
        $objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Path\To\Docu\Vorlage\Doc1.docx") 
    } else {
        $objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Path\To\\Docu\Vorlage\Doc2.docx") 
    }
    $objSelection = $objWord.Selection 
    $n = 0
    while ($n -ne $dataToRaplace.Length) { 

        $FindText = $Replace[$n]
        $ReplaceWith = $dataToRaplace[$n]
        $MatchCase = $False 
        $MatchWholeWord = $true
        $MatchWildcards = $False 
        $MatchSoundsLike = $False 
        $MatchAllWordForms = $False 
        $Forward = $True 
        $Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
        $Format = $False 
        $wdFindContinue = 1 
        $wdReplaceAll = 2
        $a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, `
            $MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,`
            $Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$wdReplaceAll) 
        $n++
    }
    $filename = $user_name
    $objDoc.SaveAs("C:\Path\To\Docu\$filename.docx")
    $objWord.Quit()
    if ($checkbox2.Checked -eq $true) {
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path\To\Docu\$filename.docx" -Verb print
    }


}
```

And here is error message

> ```
> This command is not available.
> At C:\Scripts\Done\Ausgabe.ps1:103 char:9
> +         $a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWh ...
> +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> ```

Comment: Have the files (Word documents) changed? When Word can't execute something the cause is sometimes because `Selection` is something that doesn't support the command. That's one of the reasons it's better to *not* use `Selection` unless there's no alternative. Declaring and instantiating a `Range` object to use instead is usually prefefable. Roughly: `$objRange = $objDoc.Content`

Comment: No, The files was not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have your document opened before doing `$objDoc.SaveAs`.

Check process manager for orphan `WINWORD.EXE` processes running.

Comment: All Word proccess are closed.